# Min, MAx SQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query and I really need help optimizing it:

```
SELECT min(p.price) as min_price, max(p.price) as max_price
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_category pc
    ON p.id_product = pc.id_product AND
       p.id_project = 1 AND
       pc.id_category = 2 AND
       p.active = 1
```

The tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id_product` bigint(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_project` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `reference_internal` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `price` float(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `old_price` float NOT NULL,
  `reduction_amount` float NOT NULL,
  `reduction_percent` float NOT NULL,
  `is_reduced` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_manufacturer` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_supplier` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `is_new` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `popularity` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_upd` datetime NOT NULL,
  `id_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `indexed` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_color` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `rating_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `viewed` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `a_id_product` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`),
  ADD KEY `id_product` (`id_product`),
  ADD KEY `reference` (`reference`),
  ADD KEY `reference_internal` (`reference_internal`),
  ADD KEY `sku` (`sku`),
  ADD KEY `reduction_amount` (`reduction_amount`),
  ADD KEY `reduction_percent` (`reduction_percent`),
  ADD KEY `is_reduced` (`is_reduced`),
  ADD KEY `id_manufacturer` (`id_manufacturer`),
  ADD KEY `id_supplier` (`id_supplier`),
  ADD KEY `is_new` (`is_new`),
  ADD KEY `popularity` (`popularity`),
  ADD KEY `date_add` (`date_add`),
  ADD KEY `date_upd` (`date_upd`),
  ADD KEY `id_category` (`id_category`),
  ADD KEY `indexed` (`indexed`),
  ADD KEY `id_color` (`id_color`),
  ADD KEY `price` (`price`),
  ADD KEY `rating` (`rating`),
  ADD KEY `a_id_product` (`a_id_product`),
  ADD KEY `t7` (`price`,`id_product`,`id_project`,`active`) USING BTREE;
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `product`
ALTER TABLE `product`
  MODIFY `id_product` bigint(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

There product_categories table:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_category` (
  `id_product` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_project` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_category` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `menu_order` int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `product_category`
--
ALTER TABLE `product_category`
  ADD KEY `id_product` (`id_product`),
  ADD KEY `id_project` (`id_project`),
  ADD KEY `id_category` (`id_category`),
  ADD KEY `menu_order` (`menu_order`),
  ADD KEY `t1` (`id_product`,`id_category`),
  ADD KEY `t2` (`id_product`,`id_project`,`id_category`);
COMMIT;
```

**The  explain statement https://snag.gy/8ClFnh.jpg**

[image]
I have 45 MS execution time but the database is not very large, i have around 20.000 products but when it's live i will have  million of products and the 0.0550 seconds execution time seems very long for this number of products, anyone can help with an optimization suggestion?

I have mysql 5.7.

Comment: @Waayd Are you suggesting the OP only needs indices on a single table?

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: "lets index every column off the table" to see if it works is a very very bad idea.

Comment: An index on `(id_project, active, price)` in the `product` table should help, at least with speeding up the max part of the query.  Not sure if a single index could cover everything.

Comment: Do you run this query for every product? It have same output for every product in category and project, mayby you should use group by to get all you need in one query execution

Comment: At first sight your query needs to atleast have these "secondary indexes" indexes `product(id_product, active)` and `product_category(id_product, id_category)` or the covering index `product(id_product, active, price)` ... But because InnoDB table engine stores the PRIMARY KEY into secondary indexes you can remove id_product column from secondary indexes..

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I have id_product, id_category index in the product_category, also only adding in the product table the following index:  id_product,id_project,active, price dropped the execution time to 37MS, but still i do not think it is enough for such a small number of products

Comment: @Adam Silenko No, this is only executed once per category page

Comment: Your index also needs to add `id_project` totally overlooked that one but you already have it.. Besides it looks like your query already was using a covering index i notice now from the explain within the image.. I would use query profiling ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html )  to see where time is spend within the 37MS.. Note that queries use random disk I/O access or RAM random I/O acces depening what is stored within the innoDB buffer pool but both I/O acces costs time depening on the used hardware

Comment: Besides i also don't see why you need to join with the product_category table because running the query `SELECT min(p.price) as min_price, max(p.price) as max_price
FROM product p
WHERE 
       p.id_project = 1 AND
       p.id_category = 2 AND
       p.active = 1 `  should give you the same results because product table already has the id_category column the join is unnecessary in this case. .

Comment: @Raymond Nijland  After adding the 4x Indexes on the product table this is the explain https://snag.gy/keAQql.jpg also, i need the product_category, as the id_category from the product table represents the default product category, but a product can be a part of 10 categories, and i need to check if the product is in a certain category, not if a product has that default category.

Comment: The query is about as fast as it can be; you’re using a primary key lookup. Could the problem be latency between the client and the server?

Comment: @Bohemian at the moment i a running the test on my working computer installed on localhost so latency cannot be an issue

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be pretty easy to optimize, if the number of rows you are selecting is low (0.5% or less of the total).

The indexes below should help:

```
create index ix1_product on product (id_project, active, price);

create index ix2_procat on product_category (id_product, id_category);
```